# Issue with @CacheEvict when invoking a AWSLambda function from Spring service

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am running into a typical issue with @CacheEvict annotation not working when invoking an AWSLambda function from Springboot App.

I have a POST controller, that has a /save endpoint. Within the controller, I invoke the AWSLambda using Java SDK using something like this:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
        public ResponseEntity<Object> saveData(@RequestBody MyDTO myDTO) {
        String cn = "123456"; //Hard coded as an example
        try {
                    InvokeResult result = getResultfromLambda(myDTO,cn);
                    String responseStr = null;
                    if(result.getPayload() != null){
                        responseStr = new String(result.getPayload().array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    }
        .......
            }catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("An exception occurred while saving data. Exception is : {}", e.getMessage());
                LogUtils.logExceptionDetails(e);
                String stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
                throw e;
            }
           ...
```

The getResultfromLambda is as below:

```
@Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(cacheNames="CACHE1", key="#cn" , cacheManager = "cacheManager"),
        @CacheEvict(cacheNames="CACHE2", key="#cn" , cacheManager = "cacheManager")
       })
public InvokeResult getResultfromLambda(MyDTO myDTP, String cn) {
    InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
            .withFunctionName(MY_SERVICE_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME)
            .withPayload(myDTO);
    req.setInvocationType(InvocationType.Event);
    return awsLambda.invoke(req);
}
```

awsLambda is autowired as below in the controller:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
AWSLambda awsLambda;
```

The Lambda get invoked but the CacheEvict does not happen. I have tried many ways of using CacheManager directly, but still does not work.

Is it because of the Asynchronous execution of the Lambda function? Could you please guide on how to resolve this?